# Trying to split array. Working but showing error

Tags: php, arrays

I want to split an array in php with explode. My array looks likes this:

```
C:\wamp64\www\SC New Skin\functions\get\userItems.php:21:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      1 => string '1,1' (length=3)
      2 => string '2,11' (length=4)
      4 => string '1,8' (length=3)
      5 => string '2,10' (length=4)
      8 => string '1,6' (length=3)
```

I want to split on the ",".

My code looks like this:

```
function getItems($array){
    $array = array_unique($array);
    foreach ($array as $key) {
        $var = explode(",", $key);
        echo $var[0];
        echo $var[1] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

This will work but gives two errors:

> **Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\SC New Skin\functions\get\userItems.php on line 20** &
>   **Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\SC New Skin\functions\get\userItems.php on line 22**

Comment: What does $key in $var = explode(",", $key); prints?

Comment: You array is a multidimension array, you use only one froeach, so the $key is an array, not string.

Comment: Thanks @KrisRoofe. I solved the problem now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be because the first element of the internal array is also an array, not a string like the other elements:

```
0 => 
   array (size=0)
        empty
```